# matrix data in python

Tags: python

I was trying to progressively subtract values of a 3D matrix. The matrix looks like:

```
ATOM 1223 ZX SOD A 11 2.11 -1.33 12.33
ATOM 1224 ZY SOD A 11 -2.99 -2.92 20.22
ATOM 1225 XH HEL A 12 -3.67 9.55 21.54
ATOM 1226 SS ARG A 13 -6.55 -3.09 42.11
...
```

here the last three columns are representing values for axes x,y,z respectively.
now I what I wanted to do is, take the values of x,y,z for 1st line and subtract with 2nd,3rd,4th line in a iterative way and print the values for each axes.
I was using:

```
for line in map(str.split,inp):
    x = line[-3]
    y = line[-2]
    z = line[-1]
```

for separating the values, but how to do in iterative way. should I do it by using `Counter`.
Expected output:
for line1 vs line2: `5.1 1.59 -7.89`
for line1 vs line3: `5.78 -10.88 -9.21`
...so on.

Comment: What do you mean by iterative way?

Answer (score 1):

This would give you a list of [x,y,z] lists that you could iterate over/unpack.

```
mylist = [map(float, line[-3:]) for line in map(str.split, inp)]
```

But if you want to iteratively produce the result of subtracting new rows of values from x,y,z, your best bet is to write a generator function, like this:

```
def matrix_gen(inp):
    """ iteratively subtracts values from first line of input 3D matrix """
    if len(inp) < 1: raise StopIteration
    first_line = inp[0].split()
    x,y,z = map(float, first_line[-3:])
    yield x,y,z
    for elem in inp[1:]:
        line = elem.split()
        new_x, new_y, new_z = map(float, line[-3:])
        yield x - new_x, y - new_y, z - new_z
```

The generator will first yield your initial x,y,z value, and then afterwards will yield the result of subtracting the next value of x,y,z from your matrix from the previous value. Then you can generate your (x,y,z) tuples via:

```
for x,y,z in matrix_gen(inp):
    # do something
```

If you don't want to print the first line, just remove that first `yield` statement.

Looks like you want a string as output, you could generate a list of strings for this by doing:

```
[' '.join(x) for x in matrix_gen(inp)]
```

Answer (score 0):

`itertools` is better:

```
import itertools

ss = ['ATOM 1223 ZX SOD A 11 2.11 -1.33 12.33',
      'ATOM 1224 ZY SOD A 11 -2.99 -2.92 20.22',
      'ATOM 1225 XH HEL A 12 -3.67 9.55 21.54',
      'ATOM 1226 SS ARG A 13 -6.55 -3.09 42.11']

mylist = [map(float, i.split()[-3:]) for i in ss]
print [list(itertools.imap(lambda x,y: x - y, i[0], i[1])) for i in itertools.combinations(mylist, 2)]
```